# Is there a function to obtain pooled standardized coefficient of linear equation modelling related to analysis of a MI database?

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-mice

I replaced missing data by using MICE package.
I realized the linear equation modelling by using : `summary(pool(with(imputed_base_finale,lm(....)))`

I tried to obtain standardized coefficients by using the function lm.beta, however it doesn't work.

```
lm.beta (with(imputed_base_finale,lm(...)))

Error in lm.beta(with(imputed_base_finale, lm(...))) 
  object has to be of class lm
```

How can I obtain these standardized coefficients ?

Thank you for you help!!!

Answer (score 0):

`lm.scale` works on `lm` objects and adds standardized coefficients. This however was not build to work on `mira` objects.

Have you considered using `scale` on the data before you build a model, effectively getting standardized coefficients?
Instead of standardizing the data before imputation, you could also apply it with post processing during imputation. 
I am not sure which of these would be the most robust option.

```
require(mice)

# non-standardized
imp <- mice(nhanes2)
pool(with(imp,lm(chl ~ bmi)))

# standardized
imp_scale <- mice(scale(nhanes2[,c('bmi','chl')]))
pool(with(imp_scale,lm(chl ~ bmi)))
```